# Trying to switch MSVC for Intel compiler and getting LNK1243 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, linker-errors, icc

#### Background

I'm trying to replace the compiler of a static library currently built in VS2015 with the Intel compiler (Version 17.0.1.143 Build 20161005). After correcting whatever compile errors there were I started receiving a link time error `error LNK1243: invalid or corrupt file: COMDAT section 0x2E6 associated with following section 0x0`. The exact section (`0x2E6` shown) depends on if I have precompiled headers turned on or off, but the error remains the same.

#### What I've researched:

[Googling the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=LNK1243%09invalid%20or%20corrupt%20file%3A%20COMDAT%20section%20associated%20with%20following%20section) leads to a plethora of results (a total of about 7, with about 3 actually pertaining to the linking error). One was a linking error in [LLVM](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-September/090476.html), another is a Microsoft site that links to the VS2008 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/fkdh2csa(v=vs.90)) that links to a page that describes the [linking error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/x2s8e5w0(v%3Dvs.90)). The third is a [link to fixes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-2016-composer-edition-compilers-fixes-list) in the Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 that should have all been included in the version I'm using.

The Intel site says that it fixes

> /Qipo results in linker error: fatal error LNK1243: invalid or corrupt file: COMDAT section 0x30FE associated with following section 0x0

and the Microsoft site describes the error as

> The linker has detected a corrupt .obj file. A section must be associated with another section that precedes it.

I turned up the compiler output to diagnostic, but did not see anything helpful there.

#### Question

What is can cause this error (and how can the causes be fixed)? Alternatively, what should I be looking for in the *.obj files to glean a better understanding of what's going on?

Comment: Unsure whether it is or not the cause, But you cannot link obj files produced by one compiler with a different linker. You must switch both the compiler and the linker from Microsoft to Intel or neither of them.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm using the Intel linker, that seems to be what's failing. From the log: `Done executing task "XILIB" -- FAILED`.